# How to recover a deleted bookmarked query in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I accidentally deleted my bookmarked query in phpMyAdmin. Is there any way it can be restored?

Comment: Have you tried looking up your history?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is how you access your sql history.  As a note, this was only tested on my local machine;

[image]

Comment: My history is empty. I guess there's no way of recovering back the query. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: But at least I learn something new today. Phpmyadmin's history.

Answer (score 4):

On newer versions of phpMyAdmin the history and bookmarks are in the console.

Screen dump:

[image]